# regexp anything but

Tags: regex, ultraedit

I have an txt file with 65K lines. and not all are correct aligned.

So I need to replace the lines not ending with `;Yes` or `;No` with an space

Tried

```
^{^;Yes|^;No}$
```

Comment: Your question is incomplete. `regex` is not a tool but a language; it doesn't do anything by itself, you use it through a program. How do you attempt to replace the lines, what program do you use? The `regex` is syntactically incorrect, nevertheless.

Comment: oh correct.. I am using it in text editor to replace the end of lines

Comment: *"text editor"* doesn't make the question more clear. There are dozens of text editors and they use different flavours of `regex`. Which text editor?

Comment: I am using UltraEdit

Comment: This sounds like "*how do I use UltraEdit*", not a programming question.

Comment: It could be. But I am asking for the regular expression..

Comment: There's no such thing as "*the* regular expression". Every tool has its own regex implementation with its own syntax and quirks.

Comment: "*I am asking for the regular expression*" - Have you considered hiring a programmer? SO is not a "*write this code for me*" site.

Comment: @melpomene You have your orders.  Now start writing! :P

Comment: Seems I have learned my lesson in being much more specific in my questions ;) Thank you for your assistance @revo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select `Perl` while enabling Regular Expressions. Put this in `Find What`:

```
(?m)^.*$(?<!;Yes|;No)
```

Put a space character in `Replace with` input field.

Breakdown:

- `(?m)` Enable multline flag
- `^.*$` Match a whole line
- `(?<!` Start of a negative lookbehind

  - `;Yes` Last 4 characters shouldn't be ;Yes
  - `|` Or
  - `;No` ;No
- `)` End of negative lookbehind

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/pFS2IO/1)

Comment: I'm pretty sure actual Perl would require `$(?<!;Yes)(?<!;No)` there, but it's probably PCRE. :-)

Comment: You're right. But mostly when they say Perl, they mean PCRE. This is documentation page where any one can refer to https://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials-power-tips/ultraedit/perl-regular-expressions-digging-deeper.html

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to put a lookbehind _after_ the end marker `$`.  Nice way to make the lookbehind as efficient as possible +1.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following find and replace in regex mode:

**Find:**

```
^(?!.*(Yes|No);$).*$
```

**Replace:**

```
(space)
```

### Demo

This answer assumes that UltraEdit supports lookarounds.  If not, then it won't work, and we would need an alternative approach.